# With CasperJs, how to print log in the DOM environment?

Tags: javascript, logging, casperjs

I am new to CasperJs. I have this code and wondered how to get log messages from the getLog function.

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: "debug"
});

function getLog() {
    console.log('inside getLog');
    return 111;
}

casper.start('http://google.fr/', function () {
    this.log('page loaded', 'info');
});

casper.then(function() {
    this.log('calling getLog', 'debug');
    value = this.evaluate(getLog);
    this.log('value = ' + value, 'info');
});

casper.run();
```

The function getLog() got called because I got info message 'value = 111'. I am not able to get the message 'inside getLog' printed out on console. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this right after you initialize `casper`

```
casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
    this.echo(msg);
});
```

Comment: The [API](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate) does a pretty good job at explaining it.
For the most part, it's just that `evaluate()` runs in a contained instance that can't interact back except for passing arguments and returning variables.